# Почему нельзя изменить элементы массива через присвоение новых значений?

Tags: c#

Почему нельзя изменить элементы массива через присвоение новых значений?

Например, вот так:

```
int [] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

x = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 }
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Вы так не меняете элементы массива, вы так пытаетесь создать новый массив заполненный его другими значениями. Только вот нету в C# такого инициализатора как `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, есть `new[] {1, 2, 3}`, а также есть `int[] x = {1, 2, 3}` где вы обязаны сначала указать тип массива. В C# 12 появился новый способ инициализации, который в данном случае сработает, а именно `x = [ 9, 8, 7 ]`, но повторю, так вы **не меняете**, а **создаете новый массив** с новыми данными, учитывайте это.